# Why don't we have SE Medical?

Tags: discussion

This question has hunted me for a long time, I can only find this Medical proposal on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/59430/medical).
why don't we have SE medical? Maybe there are some histories I am not familiar with?

Comment: Because apparently not enough people are interested in or know about the proposal.

Comment: Also because if there'll be, then someone may require `SE cooking` :D

Comment: Luckily [there is no such site](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/) @MarounMaroun.

Comment: @Bart I didn't see this coming LOL

Comment: Because we don't want our doctors and nurses gaining their knowledge from teh interwebs? All joking aside, what would you do with down voted questions on that site - they would have to be tidied up real quick. I imagine it could be very popular, but some of the ramifications for dodgy advice would be scary.

Comment: the question is hunting you?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Dear Sir, that question does not say much why we don't have a medical site.

Comment: @AveMaleficum fair point, but I don't think you will get any real answer, there is no "history" or anything, as the first comment says the proposal simply did not get enough attention yet.

Comment: @ShadowWizard That's weird, I think using SE Community style will certainly run a success medical site.

Comment: Maybe so, but we can't affect people's mind.